# How to randomize a foreign key value in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `MyTable`, which has a foreign key field `OtherTableID`.

I already have a few thousand rows in `MyTable`.  Now I want to randomize `OtherTableID` so that it has some random (but valid) value of an entry in `OtherTable`.

Any ideas how to do this in one neat query, short of using a cursor?

Comment: Have you got update cascade on?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - I can do, if that'll help.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: What kind of data are you storing in the OtherTableID column, integers?

Comment: Which table has more rows? And do you care if you get duplicates?

Comment: Cascade update on you only have to update the "master" table. The DBMS will propagate the changes. Looks Like people might assume you have as well, which would be something to bear in mind.

Comment: @Byron - yes, integers

Comment: @AaronBertrand - OtherTable has more rows, and I don't care if I get duplicates.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - I don't follow.  How will this help me randomize the values of OtherTableID?

Comment: It won't. It will mean you only have to explicitly change it in one table the dbms will take care of the rest. Otherwise as soon as you try to change the key in the master table, you get told off because something is referencing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  /* apply a random row number to the other table */
  SELECT ID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())
  FROM dbo.OtherTable
),
y AS 
(
  /* apply a sequential row number to the source table */
  SELECT ID, OtherTableID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
  FROM dbo.MyTable
)
/* now perform an update using a join on those row numbers */
UPDATE y SET OtherTableID = x.ID
  FROM y INNER JOIN x
  ON y.rn = x.rn;
```

This should not produce duplicates as long as `dbo.OtherTable.ID` is unique. Also this relies on what you said - there are more rows in `dbo.OtherTable`.

Comment: Why does it have a semicolon before `WITH`?

Comment: @Shaul because a semi-colon is required to terminate the statement preceding `WITH`. Since [most people still don't do this, even though they should](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/12/21/16567.aspx), if they copy and paste my code, they complain that it breaks (when really the problem is that they were missing a semi-colon). So I include it. It doesn't hurt anything - `SELECT 1;;;;;;;;;;;;;SELECT 2;` is valid T-SQL.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link about semicolons becoming mandatory - I had no idea!

Answer (score 0):

Edit 5 : After testing, this work like a charm if you don't care about duplicate. 100% random. You can tweak it to not allow duplicate.

```
;WITH X AS
(
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IdOtherTable) AS 'Row', IdOtherTable
    FROM    OtherTable
)




UPDATE  MyTable
SET     IdOtherTable = (SELECT IdOtherTable
             FROM    X
             WHERE   Row =   round((SELECT RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(IdOtherTable) 
                                              FROM      OtherTable)), 0, 1) + 1)
```